# Acces data from a MainFragment from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, navigationcontroller

My only activity host `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` but implementation of UI-Recyclerview is done in MainFragment.

From menu i would like to sort the list of Recyclerview. So i need to get the list then manipulate then to post back to MainFragment.

Please if someone know how to do this ?

Comment: Please post your code what you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can receive menu callbacks directly in the fragment, so you don't have to involve the activity. In your fragment `onCreate` call:

```
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Then implement the related menu handling callbacks in your fragment.

Check https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#ActionBar